# Datadog: Use a tag value in an alias

Tags: statsd, datadog

I have a timeseries graph in a time board that displays data for one metric that has multiple tags called "page". The graph has one line for each tag and I'm running functions on the values, so the query for my data is "ewma_5(avg:client.load_time{env:prod}) by {page}". This query means the tooltip values when I hover on the graph are things like "ewma_5(avg:client.load_time{env:prod})".

I want to know if there is anyway to use the alias function with the tag value in it, so something like "alias": "{page}"?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I am struggling with the same thing (and this is very simple in Grafana, so I am surprised that it's not easy in Datadog!)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I've not found an answer yet.

Comment: Good question. Same need here. There is a feature request to upvote somewhere?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I asked DataDog support, and apparently as of January 2020 this is not possible, but is a feature request in their backlog. I know this is not a great answer to the question but if I hear that this changes, I will update my answer.